# Antlr4 How to Capture Evaluation Order of expressions

Tags: antlr4

I have the following grammar

```
grammar Expr;   

prog: expr;

expr: LP expr RP
| expr LP expr RP
| LP expr RP expr
| expr '*' '{' ',' expr 
| expr op=NOT expr
| expr op=AND expr
| expr op=OR expr
| ID
;

NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ; 

NOT: '~';    
AND: '&';
OR: '|';

LP : '(';
RP : ')';

// lexer/terminal rules start with an upper case letter
ID
  :
    (
    'a'..'z'
    | 'A'..'Z'
    | '0'..'9' | ' '
    | ('+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'_')
  | '='
  | '~'
  | '{'
  | '}'
  | ','
  )+ 
  ;

WS : [ \t\n]+ -> skip ;
```

I want to extract the nodes of the expression being evaluated and need it in the order in which it will be evaluated.
So for a expression such as 1*{A42,A53,A16,A3}&(A26|A41)&(A51=P&A2=F|A7=C)
It will be evaluated in the following order

```
A26 | A41 
A51 & A2=F
A51 & A2F | AF=C
1*{A42,A53,A16,A3}&(A26|A41)
1*{A42,A53,A16,A3}&(A26|A41)&(A51=P&A2=F|A7=C)
```

The main interest is figuring out the order in which the expression is evaluated.

How do you go about this. I tried writing a visitor implementation but do not know how to extract the order.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you recurse through the 'expr' rule, Antlr will generate a new context object.  The order of the contexts will provide the information you want.  Each context that contains a non-null TerminalNode for ID will represent a evaluation success.  So, in the simplest case, walk the parse tree and in 'enterEveryRule'watch for ID.  In 'enterEveryRule' and 'exitEveryRule' watch for the highest inflection points (ascending switching to descending and vice versa) between successes to distinguish between valid and unused conjunction symbols.

FWIW, your first three rule alts are ambiguous, the fourth is unlikely to do what you expect, and 5-7 can be combined to simplify your analysis.